# Viewing word office document in java applet inside firefox

Tags: java, firefox, ms-word, applet, ole

I am trying to view a .doc/.docx microsoft word files in a webpage on firefox. When all failed i tried creating an applet that will hold an instance of Word OLE to view the document.

I created the applet using: org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OleClientSite, and with in eclipse it works fine and i can see Word inside.

I created a .jar file and i tried to use the applet inside the webpage in firefox. The applet starts but i can't see anything inside.

Here is my applet code:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
public class JWordViewer  extends Applet {
  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display display;
  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell swtParent;
  java.awt.Canvas awtParent;

  public void init() {
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout(1, 1));
        awtParent = new java.awt.Canvas();
        add(awtParent);
        display = new org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display();
        swtParent = org.eclipse.swt.awt.SWT_AWT.new_Shell(display,
            awtParent);
        swtParent.setLayout(new org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout());
        org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OleFrame frame = new org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OleFrame(
            swtParent, org.eclipse.swt.SWT.NONE);
        org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OleClientSite site;
        try {
          site = new org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OleClientSite(frame,
              org.eclipse.swt.SWT.NONE, "Word.Document");

        } catch (org.eclipse.swt.SWTException e) {
          String str = "Create OleClientSite Error" + e.toString();
          System.out.println(str);
          return;
        }
        setSize(500, 500);
        validate();
        site.doVerb(org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OLE.OLEIVERB_SHOW);

        while (swtParent != null && !swtParent.isDisposed()) {
          if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
        }
      }
    });
    thread.start();
  }

  public void stop() {
    if (display != null && !display.isDisposed()) {
      display.syncExec(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
          if (swtParent != null && !swtParent.isDisposed())
            swtParent.dispose();
          swtParent = null;
          display.dispose();
          display = null;
        }
      });
      remove(awtParent);
      awtParent = null;
    }
  }
}
```

`

Any idea why isn't it working?

Here is what the Java Console says:

`basic: Told clients applet is started
Exception in thread "Thread-11" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:130)
    at JWordViewer$1.run(JWordViewer.java:17)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.util.PropertyPermission sun.arch.data.model read)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPropertyAccess(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.getProperty(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.<clinit>(C.java:21)
    ... 3 more`

And that's after i told it to trust this applet...

Comment: You are getting an access denied error. Do you have permission to read the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer: It needs permissions to read and execute on the disc.
One option is to sign the .jar file. And the other option is to give permissions to the disc.

I used for testing the second option: I modified the java.policy file like that:
`
grant codeBase "http://localhost/-" {
    permission java.io.FilePermission "<>", "read, write, execute, delete";
    permission java.net.SocketPermission "*", "accept, connect, listen, resolve";
    permission java.util.PropertyPermission "*", "read, write";
    permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "*";
    permission java.awt.AWTPermission "showWindowWithoutWarningBanner";
};

And that's solved it.

Comment: If the question is solved you can accept your own answer, I think. So that it doesn't look like it is unanswered.